# Cons for using GROUP BY ALL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

I've always looked at the `ALL` keyword in the context of `GROUP BY` clause as really useful and meaningful. I didn't experience any performance issues when using it.

[MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175028%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) states that it's going to be EOL (since 2005), and recommend not to use it in production code, but still supports it until latest versions of SQL Server.

Is there any performance impact or other practical reason for not using it?

Comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/05/group-by-all.aspx and it isn't part of the ANSI SQL standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace

```
SELECT AggregateFunction(AggColumn) 
FROM ... 
WHERE Predicate GROUP BY ALL GrpColumn
```

with

```
SELECT AggregateFunction(CASE WHEN Predicate THEN AggColumn END) 
FROM ... 
GROUP BY GrpColumn
```

Example:

```
SELECT  p.ProductID, MAX(p.UnitPrice) AS MAX_UnitPrice
FROM (
    SELECT 1, 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 10.5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 55 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 99
) p(ProductID, UnitPrice)
WHERE p.ProductID = 1
GROUP BY ALL p.ProductID;

SELECT  p.ProductID, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN p.ProductID = 1 THEN p.UnitPrice END) AS MAX_UnitPrice
FROM (
    SELECT 1, 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 10.5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 55 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 99
) p(ProductID, UnitPrice)
GROUP BY ALL p.ProductID;
```

**Edit 1:**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

PRINT 'Test #1: GROUP BY ALL'
SELECT  p.ProductModelID, 
        MAX(p.ListPrice) AS MAX_ListPrice
FROM    Production.Product p
WHERE   p.Color = 'Red'
GROUP BY ALL p.ProductModelID

PRINT 'Test #2: GROUP BY + MAX(CASE WHEN)'
SELECT  p.ProductModelID, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN p.Color = 'Red' THEN p.ListPrice END) AS MAX_ListPrice
FROM    Production.Product p
GROUP BY p.ProductModelID
```

STATISTICS IO Output:

```
Test #1: GROUP BY ALL
Table 'Product'. Scan count 2, logical reads 30

Test #2: GROUP BY + MAX(CASE WHEN)
Table 'Product'. Scan count 1, logical reads 15
```

Actual execution plans:
[image]

From the point of view of performance, from this test (I used [Adventure Works 2008 R2](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases)) we can see that GROUP BY ALL forces SQL Server to read the same data twice:

- The execution plan has two Index Scan operators,
- The output of STATISTICS IO ON shows also 2 scans and the num. of logical reads (in my test) for GROUP BY ALL is greater than the num. of logical reads for non GROUP BY ALL solution. Also, creating indexes will not change this situation: 2 operators Scan and/or Seek for `GROUP BY ALL` **vs.** 1 operator Scan or Seek for `GROUP BY + MAX(CASE WHEN)` .

Comment: @Yosi: [1] Being a deprecated feature should be enough to not use it. Maybe in one/two major release this feature will be removed but will be used [still] in compatibility mode (ex. SQL Server 2016 :-) with compatibility mode SQL Server 2008). [2] See Edit #1.

Comment: Note: there are at least two deprecated features which I still use them: SQL Trace/SQL Profiler (more) and Database Mirroring (less).